# How to display records belongs to categories in django

Tags: python, django

I have a **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Kategorie(models.Model):
    glowna = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Kategoria')
    slug_kat = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Odnośnik', default='')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Kategoria'
        verbose_name_plural='Kategorie'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.glowna


class Witryna(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField(default="", max_length=150, verbose_name = 'Nazwa strony')
    adres_www = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name='Adres www')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Przyjazny adres url', unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Adres e-mail')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=3000, verbose_name='Opis strony')
    kategoria = models.ForeignKey(Kategorie, verbose_name='Kategoria')
    data_publikacji = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data publikacji')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Strona www'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Strony www'

    def publikacja(self):
        self.data_publikacji=timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa
```

and i have created **view** :

```
def detale_kat(request, slug_kat):
konkretna_kategoria = Witryna.objects.annotate(cnt_witryna=Count('kategoria')).order_by('kategoria')
return render(request, 'firmy/detale_kat.html', {'konkretna_kategoria': konkretna_kategoria})
```

on the end in html fil i have a django tags like:

```
{% extends 'firmy/index3.html' %}
{% block kategoria %}
{%for konkret in konkretna_kategoria%}
{{ konkret.cnt_witryna }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

In my app on the main html file I have a view of 56 categories whos were added by the Kategorie class. The list of display categories is the detail view. How to use definition when I click in link of for example category "Business", and I want to display all websites whos were added in that category. The annotate is a good method or I have to use filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want filter records, use `filter`.

In the view:

```
def detale_kat(request, slug_kat):
    konkretna_kategoria = Witryna.objects.annotate(cnt_witryna=Count('kategoria')).order_by('kategoria')
    websites = Witryna.objects.filter(kategoria__slug_kat=slug_kat)
    return render(request, 'firmy/detale_kat.html', 
                  {'konkretna_kategoria': konkretna_kategoria, 
                  'websites': websites})
```

In html:

```
...
{% for website in websites %}
    {{ website.nazwa }}
{% endfor %}
...
```